# How do I save multiple buffers (of my choosing) at the same time in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, save

When I press `C-x s` (`save-some-buffers`)  or `C-x C-c` (`save-buffers-kill-terminal`), Emacs displays the names of modified buffers one by one and asks what to do with each (save, diff, pass, ...). Pressing `y` one by one is slow. Pressing `!` doesn't let you see what buffers are being saved.

How can I have the names of all modified buffers displayed first so that I can mark off some of them and save all the other quickly?

Comment: so what you want is not to save _all_ modified buffers. The title is misleading.

Comment: I edited it. It should be less confusing now.

Answer (score 17):

`C-x C-b` (`M-x list-buffers`) displays a list of all the buffers. Modified ones will be shown with a `*` next to them. You can mark a buffer for saving by pressing `s`. When you're done, press `x` to save all the buffers you marked.

Unfortunately, as far as I know, there's no way to show only the unsaved buffers or to sort them so they're all at the top.

(I actually prefer `M-x ibuffer` to `M-x list-buffers`, but `ibuffer` provides a similar feature.)

Answer (score 16):

In emacs 23, with ibuffer :

- 'M-x ibuffer' (to open a list of buffers)
- '*u' (start and u at the same time) to marked all unsaved buffers
- 'S' to save all marked buffers

Strangely enough, *u does not mark 'special' buffers like *scratch*, *compilation*, etc... I suppose i regexps on the name ...

Comment: Re: `*scratch*` etc, it simply doesn't mark "unsaved" buffers which have no `buffer-file-name` to save to.

Answer (score 4):

Use `ibuffer`, which should come with all late-model emacsen.  Put the following in your .emacs file:

```
(autoload 'ibuffer "ibuffer" "" t)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") 'ibuffer)


(defun my-ibuffer-load-hook ()
  "Hook for when ibuffer is loaded."

  (define-ibuffer-filter unsaved-file-buffers
   "Only show unsaved buffers backed by a real file."
 (:description "unsaved file buffers")
 (and (buffer-local-value 'buffer-file-name buf)
   (buffer-modified-p buf)))

  (define-key ibuffer-mode-map (kbd "/ *") 'ibuffer-filter-by-unsaved-file-buffers)
  )

;; (add-hook 'ibuffer-load-hook 'my-ibuffer-load-hook)

(eval-after-load 'ibuf-ext '(my-ibuffer-load-hook))
```

Then use `C-x C-b` to bring up the ibuffer list, and `/ *` to show just unsaved buffers backed by a real file (so you don't see `*scratch*` in the list, for example).  Mark the desired buffers with `m` and then save them with `S`.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the question in the title is to pass an argument to save-buffers-kill-emacs (or -kill-terminal), ie. use the key combo `C-u C-x C-c` which will silently save all buffers and exit (or `C-u C-x s` to just silently save all buffers).

Comment: Why would I want to kill emacs?

Answer (score 2):

In emacs 23

- `C-x C-b` (`M-x list-buffers`) to view buffer list
- `m` to mark buffers to save
- `S` to save marked buffers
- `u` to unmark buffers individually or `M-x dired-unmark-all-marks` for all

Comment: This is the correct solution for the question in the body (not for the question in the title, which is misleading)

Answer (score 2):

I have googled now for this question and found the solution here
http://johntellsall.blogspot.com.es/2013/03/emacs-save-all-modified-buffers.html

You have to add this config to your ~/.emacs.d/init.el emacs configuration

```
(global-set-key 
 (kbd "M-*")
 (lambda ()
   (interactive)
   (save-some-buffers t)))
```

save and eval the buffer (M-evalb-buffer) of the init.el file, and then when you want to save all the modified files you only have to press Meta key with "*" as is indicated in the second line

I hope this solution works!

Juan